# Why doesn't git pull bring back directories that I've deleted?

Tags: git

I've just started learning how to use `git` today, progressing well.

As an experiment, I used `push` to upload two directories (containing two files each) and two files in the root directory. This worked fine.

I then deleted one of the two directories that I have locally (but not on git). When I use `git status` it seems to be aware of this:

> `deleted: test/Testfile.as`
>   `deleted: test/Testile2.as`

But when I use `git pull` to get my files back, they don't seem to return to my local folder. I've also tried `git fetch`.

The only way I seem to be able to get everything back is `git clone`, but that doesn't seem logical as I need to delete my master directory locally and then clone it back again (or  alternatively specify a new location for the cloned files).

What is the appropriate way to retrieve files and folders from github that have been deleted locally?

Comment: A key concept you might be missing is that push and pull are about transferring *commits* between the remote and local repository. If you want to deal with differences between your work tree and the currently checked out commit, that's a completely local operation.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`git pull` just merges the fetched commits in your working directory and will not restore your deleted directory ( but might warn you about conflicts.)

If you have deleted the folders in your working directory, you have to do:

```
git checkout -- test
```

to get it back.

Or you can do `git reset --hard` to completely bring your working directory to HEAD state.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. On the back of this question, why don't the directories on git get deleted when I `git push` after deleting them locally?

Comment: @MartyWallace - you have to do a `git rm` and stage the deletion, commit and push.

Comment: This answer could be made more clear as the command `git checkout -- test` will restore the files only in the *`test`* directory, but with no helpful command line feedback (they simply re-appear). The general command `git checkout` will give you a useful list of locally deleted files. Note that `git checkout -- .` will restore from the root directory.

Answer (score 14):

you want to return your repository to the previous working version. this is a job for git-reset.

```
git reset --hard
```

be sure to read through this [useful explanation of git-reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

you could also check out those files if you wanted to:

```
git checkout -- test/
```

Answer (score 3):

git pull will merge in changes. think of it like a file you've modified. a git pull doesn't replace the contents of the file with the remotes copy if you've modified it. even if there is a conflicting change, then it just warns you of a fastforward.

If you have your repository in a state where the delete is the only uncommitted change, and you want to undo it, then do a `git reset head --hard`

Or, if you have other changes you want to leave in place, do `git checkout -- test`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `git pull` and `git checkout`, `git revert` also will be helpful to get back the deleted files

Answer (score -1):

`git reset --hard <commit hash>` means HEAD will be pointing at a particular commit and whatever commits you've made after that commit hash won't be available. The reason for this is because you are pointing HEAD to separate commit HASH. If you push forcibly then you will lose all commits.

Note: Be carefull when using `git reset --hard` command in git.