# Pushed my files, but don't get the changes with git pull

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am new to git. I pushed all my files with following `git add files/map`, `git commit -m`, `git push` and decided to remove them from my hard drive because to use `git pull`. When i do that i don't get the changes.

Comment: What does happen? What output do you get?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843577/how-to-restore-deleted-file?lq=1 . In general, pull will try to merge the remote repository with yours, but it will not discard the changes you have made (=deleted files). But I think you shold also be receiving a warning or an error message

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305326/why-doesnt-git-pull-bring-back-directories-that-ive-deleted
You need to use reset or checkout.

Answer (score 0):

In general, git pull fetches and merges changes from a remote repository into the current branch. That's why you don't get the changes back.